# How to make raycasting very accurate?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using `raycast` to detect the object the player is looking at so it can be picked up. However, it is not very accurate. in my game all small objects are pickable. I'm facing a problem when trying to pick up an item next to many other pickable items because when I'm looking directly at one item and click the pick-up button, it picks another near item instead of the one I'm currently looking at.

```
        raycastPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.SphereCast(raycastPos, sphereCastRadius, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
                {
                    lookObject = hit.collider.transform.gameObject;
                }
                else
                {
                    lookObject = null;
        }  
    
    
     if (PickingUp)
            {
                if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
                {
                    if (lookObject != null)
                    {
                        
                        PickupObject();
                        if (lookObject.CompareTag("TargetObj") && !targetObjectsList.Contains(lookObject.gameObject))
                        {
                            if (aSource)
                            {
                                aSource.Play();
                            }
                            targetObjectsList.Add(lookObject.gameObject); 
                            if (targetObjectsList.Count == targetObjects.Length)
                            {
    //
                            }
    
    
    
                        }
                        CenterIcon.SetActive(false);
                    }
    
                }
                else
                {
                   // pickupRB.transform.position = PickupParent.position;
                    BreakConnection();
}
```

How can I make the raycasting very accurate so only the object I'm pointing to gets picked?

Comment: Use a sphere cast or a box cast… rather than something which is essential almost a pixel test.

Comment: I'm using SphereCast in the if statement. here: if (Physics.SphereCast(raycastPos, sphereCastRadius, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))

Comment: Make the radius smaller? Or use a straight normal raycast.

Comment: The normal raycast did the trick. Thank you. if you would like, you can add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spherecaat/boxcast cover an area which can be great for small objects as the user does not have to be pixel perfect to click on them especially bid they have a mesh collider such as a key. However. If you have many objects near each other a wider cast can mean other objects are picked up first. Decreasing the radius so only 1 object is covered is one way or using a normal raycast will be more accurate at the expense of needing to be more accurately over said item